# Заварил кашу...на Swift_e

Tags: swift

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[9])!)
```

(так работает...*.storyboard не нужен...)

а хочется так =

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage!(named: (UInt32(arc4random_uniform(9))), background)!)
```

(чтобы при каждом запуске background был разный...)

ругается

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIImage!' with an argument list of type '(named: (UInt32), [String])'
```

и как бы починить...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(background.count)))])!)
```